# Workspace with multiple Dart / Flutter projects, how to tell VSCode to run a specific one

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I have a workspace with 7 different Dart / Flutter projects.  Currently, to choose which project to run, I select a file from that project and then f5.  Using this approach seems to be quite error prone as I sometimes have the wrong file open and it loads the wrong project.  Other times I it takes a few seconds to find a file and open it to run.

It would be nice if there was a selector for me to choose which project or a way to select a default project to run regardless of which file I have open.  Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control this by creating a Launch Configuration (see https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations) file (`launch.json`). You can create this by clicking the Cog icon on the Debug side bar. It'll be created at `.vscode/launch.json`.

You can set the `cwd` or `program` fields in the config to relative paths from the folder you've opened to control what launches. `program` lets you specify a specific script, whereas `cwd` lets you specify a project root (where the Dart plugin will try to guess the best entry point, like `bin/main.dart` for Dart, or `lib/main.dart` for Flutter).

Another option is to use VS Code's "Multi-Root Workspaces", where you'll be able to select which workspace folder to debug from the debug side bar, however this generally results in saving a `.code-workspace` file that some users (including myself) find an annoyance.